# Não consigo extrair um arquivo com senha usando o DotNetZip

Tags: c#

Estou tentando extrair um arquivo chamado "1.zip" com uma senha aleatória que eu mesmo coloquei...
porém estou tendo um erro.
"e was null".

To no ponto de queimar o PC, sou iniciante no C#, não sei POO ainda, to no início, não consigo resolver esse problema...

Segue o link do código, não consegui formatar.

https://pastebin.com/iESVMDBq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara, eu vi seu código e fiz uma pequena implementação e rodou.

Primeiro eu coloquei o caminho inteiro do local de leitura concatenado com o nome do arquivo zip.

Depois especifiquei o arquivo dentro do arquivo .zip que você quer pegar e salvar em outro diretório e funcionou.

Coloquei as variáveis separadas para que simplifique a sua leitura.

**Uma dica** que eu te dou é para nunca utilizar acentos ou espaços para trabalhar com programação igual está no seu namespace (namespace tentativa_de_extra**çã**o_do_arquivo) e no seu diretório para localizar o seu arquivo.

Segue abaixo o código

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string nomeDoArquivoZIP = "1.zip";
        string senhaDoArquivo = "w5KxT";

        var diretorioLerArquivo = @"C:\Stackoverflow\BRKappa";
        var diretorioSalvarArquivo = @"C:\Stackoverflow\BRKappa\output";
        var caminhoCompleto = diretorioLerArquivo + "\\" + nomeDoArquivoZIP;
        var nomeArquivoDentroArquivoZIP = "1.txt";


        using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(caminhoCompleto))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(diretorioSalvarArquivo);
            foreach (ZipEntry e in zip)
            {
                if (e.FileName == nomeArquivoDentroArquivoZIP)
                    e.ExtractWithPassword(diretorioSalvarArquivo, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently, senhaDoArquivo);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Realmente, funcionou, obrigado, muita gente acaba nem tentando ajudar... Como sou iniciante, não estava conseguindo resolver de jeito nenhum(passei o dia inteiro tentando). Eu consigo aplicar isso em um loop usando for, certo? Porque assim, eu tenho uma sequência de arquivos. "1.zip" contém o "2.zip", "2.zip" contém o "3.zip"(assim por diante). Até +ou- 300, eu tenho a senha de cada um deles, da pra descompactar um por um sem ter que ficar descompactando na mão, certo? Mas, enfim, obrigado, a única coisa que tive que alterar foi o "var nomeArquivoDentroArquivoZip = "2.zip".

Comment: Sim, dá pra fazer. E se eu entendi certo o seu problema, ele é uma loucura, .zip dentro de .zip até realmente chegar no seu arquivo real. O que você terá que fazer é criar um índice com o número do seu arquivo e a respectiva senha para ele, e no seu for, na hora de chamar o ExtractWithPassword pegar essa senha pelo index e extrair. O nome do arquivo "1.txt" foi apenas o exemplo que eu coloquei para testar seu código.

Comment: É uma loucura mesmo, haha. É pra um projeto diferente. E realmente, pensei no índice, mas, de qualquer forma, valeu!!